# sorting a while function

Tags: php, sorting

I have a purchase log in my webshop admin, one costumer buy many products, all products are marked with SKU and i want to sort and group my purchase log by sku.

Is there any way to sort this and group them?

It purchase log SKU could look like this:

```
27318
15277
14065
6236
vild-100
N/A
blomsterkasser-40g
16694
7147
24608
```

and the sorted version i am looking for:

```
6236
7147
14065
15277
16694
24608
27318
blomsterkasser-40g
vild-100
N/A
```

Here is the code:

```
private function purchase_log_cart_items() {
while( wpsc_have_purchaselog_details() ) :
wpsc_the_purchaselog_item(); ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo wpsc_purchaselog_details_quantity(); ?> x </td> <!-- QUANTITY! -->
<td><?php echo wpsc_purchaselog_details_name(); ?></td> <!-- NAME! -->
<td><?php echo wpsc_purchaselog_details_SKU(); ?></td> <!-- SKU! -->
<td>
<?php
echo wp.....
```

Comment: have you tried `sort`?

Comment: @kuh-chan That probably doesn't work since 'N/A' is the last entry in the list.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [`usort`](https://php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php) and a custom sort function:

```
$array = [
    27318,
    15277,
    14065,
    6236,
    'vild-100',
    'N/A',
    'blomsterkasser-40g',
    16694,
    7147,
    24608
];

usort($array, function($left, $right) {
    // else 'blomsterkasser-40g' would be the first entry
    $left = (string) $left;
    $right = (string) $right;
    // always put 'N/A' on the last position
    if($left == 'N/A' && $right == 'N/A') {
        return 0;    
    }else if($left == 'N/A') {
        return 1;
    } else if($right == 'N/A') {
        return -1;
    }

    return $left <=> $right;
});

var_dump($array);
```

Working code: https://3v4l.org/2K5sO